# Anywhere - Free sketch Diagram and PDF conversion

Tags: maximo-anywhere

Am customizing Anywhere (7.6), Can we draw free sketch and upload as a picture, Also can we convert any image into PDF using Anywhere ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend Anywhere to add your own (or other third party) custom javascript libraries.  Anywhere 7.6 has a jSignature plugin to capture signatures that you can reuse in your pages to perform your own sketch capture with javascript code.  Take a look at the platform/signature/handler/SignatureHandler code for an example.

Comment: Thanks Scott.Let me give a try. If possible, share any free sketch plugin details that I can use.